# Pull request policies - Build expired - How can I run the build again?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build

I have made a pull request which has some policies. 
The pull request has been approved and is ready to complete, but since the build has been expired, I cannot Complete it. Here is the status of policies:

*Required*

- ✔️ 2 reviewer approved
- ✔️ Work items linked
- ❌ Build expired

*Optional*

- ✔️ All comments resolved

In Visual Studio, in Team Explorer, in Builds, I see my build with a green check mark, but when I right click on the build, *Retry Build* is disabled.

How can I run the build again?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally you can rebuild from Pull Request overview page:

For example the build faild, the I can click the "`...`" behind the Build Validation policy item --> `Queue Build` to rebuild it.

Please refer to [Pull request build policies for high quality code](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/04/21/pull-request-build-policies-for-high-quality-code/) for details.

More information please refer to [Build validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=vsts#build-validation), and a similar thread for your reference : [VSTS Build expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46193136/vsts-build-expired)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andy. The command is *Queue build* for expired builds too. I clicked on that and it started a new build and the problem solved. My mistake was going to build details page (by click on the build expired link) and trying to queue a new build there, then it opened a form and asked for some information including the branch, commit, variables and so on an I was not sure specially about the variables. Anyway, long story short, instead of going to build details page, I clicked on the same menu item which you showed in the image and the problem solved. Thanks.